# Improper Integral Property of a Positive Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a positive function satisfying
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{dr}{g(r)}}=\infty.$$
Can say that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{g(r)dr}<\infty$ ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't even understand how it came to your mind. What if $g\equiv 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $g(r) = r$. Since the harmonic series diverges, then by integral test, we have

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = +\infty \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dr}{g(r)} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dr}{r} = +\infty$$

On the other hand, we also have

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} g(r)dr = \int_{0}^{\infty} rdr = +\infty$$

This makes $g(r) = r$ a counterexample to the claim.

Comment: It's truth! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. :) As @metamorphy suggested, you can even take $g(r) = 1$, that is a nice, simpler counterexample. :)